Feed Jack Clarke out the left
I don't understand the use of "out" in this context. Does it mean outside the box?

GOAL! Ipswich 1-0 Aston Villa (DELAP, 8 mins) Where has this come
from?!
The first time that Ipswich come forward, they score. Kalvin Phillips
barrels his way towards the penalty area and feeds Jack Clarke out
to the left. The ball across is good, and Liam Delap fires home.


Please give us the links. You are quoting articles and should give us the source.  This sounds like real speech. Is it?

Specifically, it sounds like a transcript of a football announcer. There's lots of jargon in sports talk.

You have been misguided by people giving you (in answers to other similar questions you have aksed) what they think are football-specific or specific-sport-specific explanations, but the standard meaning of the preposition is being used, merely in a football context or in the context of some other sport. It has nothing to do specifically with football.  If I tell you to steer your kayak or your canoe "out to the left", it means I want you to guide it away to the left of where you are, or where we both are, if we are paddling side by side.

"feeds" in this context does have a sports-specific meaning. It means to pass the ball to another (offensive) player on one's team as part of an attack on goal. Thus, "out to the left" expresses the direction and distance of the "feed", i.e. the pass.

Out takes M+W's sense 1a1:

in a direction away from the inside or center

It doesn't mean outside the box.  Clarke was in fact in the box.
Out

+1. And "center" there can have a deictic sense, with the speaker (or the interlocutor) being at the center.

This is very simple: If you are running down the field with a ball (soccer or rugby), feeding a ball means kicking (soccer) or throwing the ball (rugby) to someone.
feed is a metaphor for kick or throw. In soccer (UK football), you kick it. In rugby, you throw it.
out is not really necessary but can be used:
feeds Jack Clarke [the ball] out to the left. It emphasizes that the receiver is "out to the left of him". i.e. to his left but not super close to him. Some distance away.
